# SQL Server ошибка 15372: Не удалось сформировать пользовательский экземпляр SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Я пытаюсь подключиться к MDF. Изначально все работало, а потом в один день соединение больше не работает. Текст ошибки:

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. [CLIENT: local machine]. Error: 15372, Severity: 16, State: 1.

И перевод:

> Не удалось сформировать пользовательский экземпляр SQL Server из-за ошибки при запуске процесса для экземпляра пользователя. Соединение будет закрыто

Сама строка подключения:

```
<add name="SpDataEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\Dev\Src\bin\Debug\Sp_Data.MDF;
    Integrated Security=True;
    User Instance=True;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
<add name="MyApp.Properties.Settings.Sp_DataConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\Dev\Src\bin\Debug\Sp_Data.MDF;
    Integrated Security=True;
    User Instance=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Пробовал удалить файлы в *C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS*, перезагружать ПК. Так же запускал `sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'`, однако изменилось с 1 на 1 (иными словами были включены и до этого). Соединение работает только если установлю `User Instance=False;`. Однако данный способ не очень подходит. Прошу помочь что бы была возможность использовать `User Instance=True;`

P.S.: не являюсь администратором на ПК. Используется MS SQLServer 2012.

Comment: Я уже думал что может необходимо включить NamedPipes, но на другом ПК подключение работает нормально и стабильно без включения NamedPipes. К тому же было отключено изначально и работали (как описал в вопросе выше)